# Sinatra Heroku post not found

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

I'm trying to deploy my sinatra on Heroku https://www.heroku.com/home
I was successful before I tried post method which gave me **404**
Get methods work fine:

here is the example of the code:

```
get '/getPriceList' do //no error, everything works fine
  content_type :json, charset: 'utf-8'
  today_menu.to_json
end


post '/makeOrder', provides: :json do //error NOT FOUND
  data = request.env['rack.input'].read
  parsed_data = JSON.parse data.force_encoding('UTF-8')
  if User.where(:name => parsed_data['userName']).first.nil?
    current = Time.now
    fixed = Time.local(current.year, current.month, current.day, 18, 40, 0)
       if current > fixed
      ObedResponse.new(data, false, 'Vi ne uspeli').to_json
    else
     @user = User.create(:name => parsed_data['userName'])
    #some stuff
      end
    ObedResponse.new(data, true, "").to_json
    end
  else
    ObedResponse.new(data, false, 'Сегодня вы уже заказали').to_json
  end
```

Can someone tell me why I'm getting this error and how to make the thing work?

PS: I don't have this error while deploying locally using

```
bundle exec ruby obed.rb -e production
```

to start

Answer (score 0):

I was in the wrong branch when I commited into Heroku. Changing the branch to master solved the issue.